# Configure nodemon to refresh same tab

Tags: node.js, nodemon

This could be really rookie. I want to know if there is a way that I can configure nodemon to refresh the same tab instead of opening a new tab each time I make a change in my js files.

Answer (score 2):

Its Simple.
To run your server use
`npm start`
instead of
`nodemon server`

Answer (score 1):

`nodemon` is not able to do that. What you are looking for is something like [`browser-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync) or [`LiveReload.js`](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js).

Answer (score 1):

I use a package called reload. Assuming you are doing this on your FE and that you already installed express.js and nodemon
first install reload

```
npm install --save-dev reload
```

Than create a index.js file or server.js or whatever name your want

this is my index.js:

```js
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const reload = require('reload')
const opn = require('opn')


const app = express()

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.set('src', './src')
app.use(express.static('src'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'))

const server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening to port 8080...')
})

opn('http://localhost:8080')

reload(app)
```

the opn package can be intalled with

```
npm install opn
```

it will automatically open your localhost once you type npm start on your terminal

on HTML you have to insert something like this after the closing body tag:

```html
</body>
<script src="/reload/reload.js"></script>
```

and on package.json the following:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon index.js -e els,js,html,css,json"
```

},

The only problem with this is that it will reopen the browser every time you make a change to those files and well as reload the current opened one sure to the opn package. I am still going to create a function to prevent that, eventually. Hope that helps!

EDIT:
I have figured another way. Do not use npm opn or npm open package. Instead add this to your start on package.json: "start": "start nodemon index.js -e els,js,html,css,json & open localhost:8080"

Comment: I have figured another way. Do not use npm opn or npm open package. Instead add this to your start on package.json:     "start": "start nodemon index.js -e els,js,html,css,json & open http://localhost:8080"

Answer (score 1):

Just run `npm start nodemon server`.
It works for me. Make sure you have latest nodemon version installed.