# Reload webpack dev server when json file has being changed

Tags: json, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter that works great.

I want server to restart when I am changing the `json` file that I placed in to `src` folder. How would you do that?

**This particular `json` file I am using only in build time - no need that file when my content running in the browser.**

If I change my josn file browser does not restarts, but even if I restart it manually I can not see my changes, only if I stop and start server changes appeared in browser. My json file contains some strings that I am replacing in my html during webpack build `<%= config.title %>`.

Here is the webpack config files https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter/tree/master/webpack

I was trying to set `watch: true` but didn't help.

Also I modify this line https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter/blob/master/webpack/webpack.config.dev.js#L12 to that:

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: [Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/myconfig.json'],
    watchContentBase: true
  },
```

but have no difference

Comment: What do you mean by restart the dev server? reload the browser or reload the server itself?

Comment: @felixmosh the thing is if I change my config json file and then reload the browser manually nothing works. I had to restart the server in order to see the changes. Just updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I solved my problem using nodemon:

```
"start": "nodemon --watch content/myconfig.json 'webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js'"
```

However I have another problem, after server restated I have always new tab opened but it would be nice if just current tab gets reloaded, [not sure if it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465195/configure-nodemon-to-refresh-same-tab).

If you know better solution let me know.

Comment: checkout webpack https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon-webpack-plugin, It might help you