# Refresh current page automatically when script changes

Tags: reactjs, npm, nodemon

In recent react app I install `nodemon` globally and modified package.json to add dev command like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "nodemon ./app.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I start the app like this `npm run dev` but problem in any changes the development server start again opening new tab. How I make only current tab refreshed ?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465195/configure-nodemon-to-refresh-same-tab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure nodemon to refresh same tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465195/configure-nodemon-to-refresh-same-tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use `npm start`?

`react-scripts start` sets up the development environment and starts a server, as well as **[hot module reloading](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/)**. Read more [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#whats-included).

Comment: Problem that data inside the console does not get updated unless I refreshed manually and sometimes it refresh automatically, is that normal ?

Comment: @zac To my knowledge that doesn't happen often.  Maybe a problem with fast-refresh. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274925/development-server-of-create-react-app-does-not-auto-refresh) and could be useful